# Java OpenCSV - 2 List comparison and duplication

Tags: java, csv, import, export, opencsv

i am going to make a application, comparising 2 .csv lists, using OpenCSV.  It should works like that:

1. Open 2 .csv files ( each file has columns: Name,Emails)
2. Save results ( and here is a prbolem, i don't know if it should be save to table or something)
3. Compare From List1 and List2 value of "Emails column".
4. If Email from List 1 appear on List2 - delete it(from list 1)
5. Export results to new .csv file

I don't know if it's good algorithm. Please Tell me which option to saving results of reading .csv file is best in that case.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get around this more easily with [univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) as it can read your data into columns:

```
CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings(); //parser config with many options, check the tutorial
parserSettings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true); // uses the first row as headers

// To get the values of all columns, use a column processor
ColumnProcessor rowProcessor = new ColumnProcessor();
parserSettings.setRowProcessor(rowProcessor);

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);

//This will parse everything and pass the data to the column processor
parser.parse(new FileReader(new File("/path/to/your/file.csv")));

//Finally, we can get the column values:
Map<String, List<String>> columnValues = rowProcessor.getColumnValuesAsMapOfNames();
```

Let's say you parsed the second CSV with that. Just grab the emails and create a set:

```
Set<String> emails = new HashSet<>(columnValues.get("Email"));
```

Now just iterate over the first CSV and check if the emails are in the `emails` set.

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a hard requirement to use openCSV then here is what I believe is the easiest solution:

First off I like Jeronimo's suggestion about the HashSet.  Read the second csv file first using the CSVToBean and save off the email addresses in the HashSet.

Then create a Filter class that implements the [CSVToBeanFilter](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/bean/CsvToBeanFilter.html) interface.  In the constructor pass in the set and in the allowLine method you look up the email address and return true if it is not in the set (so you have a quick lookup).

Then you pass the filter in the CsvToBean.parse when reading/parsing the first file and all you will get are the records from the first file whose email addresses are not on the second file.  The [CSVToBeanFilter](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/bean/CsvToBeanFilter.html) javadoc has a good example that shows how this works.

Lastly use the BeanToCSV to create a file from the filtered list.

In interest of fairness I am the maintainer of the openCSV project and it is also open source and free (Apache V2.0 license).